# Create Java program that reads from the file

Tags: java

My assignment is as following Create Java program that reads from file create one person Object per line and stores object in a collection write the object out sorted by last name. this is what I have so far it compiles just fine but it doesn't print out anything. This is what I have so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       File testFile;
       Scanner fileScanner;

       try {

             testFile = new File("sample.txt");

             fileScanner = new Scanner(testFile);   
             fileScanner.useDelimiter(",");


             while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {            
                  System.out.println(fileScanner.next());       
             }

             fileScanner.close();

      }  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {          
             e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Show your content of sample.txt file.

Comment: My text file is just groups of Strings but here it is: 1233,Dana Rockman,22 Cold Hill Road, 526-3326
3234, Backy Moog,33 High Crick Ave, 714-5539
5455, Art Montgamery, 101 Heilberg Road, 663-4354
6542, Phill Duke,123 Laguna Beach Road, 834-4532
6788, Owen Biles, 446 Nebraska Road, 999-1010

Comment: You say "*but it doesn't print out anything*". Do you mean it literally?  The program you posted should print the data it reads from the file.

Comment: yes I mean it literally it doesn't print out anything. For some reason it doesn't read from the file.

Comment: Is your file in the same folder as your class/jar file?

Comment: what u trying to say i did not got it that u want to read from file and want to store in some object line by line is it??

Comment: yes it is in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

If it is a text file, please use `BufferedReader`. Then use `String#split()` to get the data. Instantiate as necessary.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(...);
String line = null;
while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
  // magic
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new to programming I am not sure how to use BufferedReader I used file Scanner instead so should I use Buffered Reader instead of the Scanner?

Comment: OK I tried but it didn't want to compile it says # in String#split() is illegal character. Should I use Number instead?

Comment: @user3316776 `String#split()` means a split method in `String` class, in your case you should use like: `System.out.println(line.split(","));`

Comment: Thank you so much I am using BufferedReader instead of Scanner. Should I do this? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `BufferedReader` is designed for reading text files so yeah !

Comment: Please if someone can help me to sort the persons objects by last name? Thanks!

Comment: BufferedReader is for reading. For sorting, you need your own algorithm. Possibly, use a `Comparator` :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want to do. But this program take a file called "sample.txt" and divide in tokens this. For example if in the txt is "carlos,jose,herrera,matos" you program out

carlos
jose
herrera
matos

now if you want to sort this, you must create a class Person and implement the Comparable

Comment: I have text file that contains 5 different persons now I want to print out these persons sorted by their last name I am sorry if I sound so confused I am new to programming.

Comment: If you asume that every Person have a name a a last name you can use this class Persona  public static class Persona implements Comparable<Persona> {
  public String name;
  public String lastname;

  public int compareTo(Persona a) {
   return this.lastname.compareTo(a.lastname);
  }

  public Persona(String name, String lastname) {
   super();
   this.name = name;
   this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
   return name + " " + lastname;
  }
 }

Comment: and this code <br>File testFile;
  Scanner fileScanner;
   testFile = new File("c:\\cj.txt");

   fileScanner = new Scanner(testFile);

   ArrayList<Persona> persons = new ArrayList<Persona>();
   
   String line = fileScanner.nextLine();;
   
   while (line != null) {
    String[] name_lastname = line.split(" ");
    Persona p = new Persona(name_lastname[0], name_lastname[1]);
    persons.add(p);
    
    line = fileScanner.nextLine();
   }

   fileScanner.close();

   Collections.sort(persons);

   for (Persona e : persons) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
    String content = null;

    while((content = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] details = content.split(",");

        int i = 1;
        for(String value : details)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    System.out.println("Name : "+value);
                    i=2;
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.println("Address : "+value);
                    i=3;
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    System.out.println("Number : "+value);
                    i = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```